# Difference in Difference and Random Treatment Timing

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference

I have a question about Difference-in-Difference estimation. It is well-known that the key identification assumption in Diff-in-Diff is the parallel trends assumption that says that in the absence of treatment, the evolution of the outcomes in the treated group would move in parallel to the control group. Of course this is a counterfactual claim.

I have been reading some papers in the literature on difference-in-difference and often encounter that the assumption that if treatment timing is as good as randomly assigned, then parallel trends will hold. This random treatment timing assumption is said to be stronger than parallel trends. My question is: can someone explain the intuition behind this?

I understand that there is selection into the treated group which implies that that group can have an initially different level of the outcome. In this way, one could say that having particular characteristics makes treatment more likely. Is it correct to say that since the random treatment timing assumption states that the probability of treatment is the same across all permutations of treatment timing, it implies that selection into the treated group must be the same over time, and that hence the parallel trend assumption holds? If so, how can one shows this?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: "[i]f treatment timing is as good as randomly assigned, then parallel trends will hold" *for the treated*. So this works if your analysis only includes (eventually) treated units.

Comment: That sounds pretty surprising given that having a never-treated group is mostly taken to be a good thing particularly when treatment is staggered.

Comment: What's surprising? That you would do an analysis that only included the treated?

Comment: No, that parallel trends hold only relative to groups that are treated at some point

Comment: I should have added: "[i]f treatment timing is as good as randomly assigned, then parallel trends will hold" *in expectation* for the treated. Not sure why this is surprising. What would be surprising is if random timing on the treated could guarantee parallel trends for the never treated, i.e. that a random timing of a policy enacted in England could guarantee parallel trends between France (or any other country) and the England counterfactual.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean!

Comment: Regarding intuition for parallel trends on the treated, if treatment timing is a random variable, than at any point in time, the average for the not yet treated should in expectation equal the average for the counterfactual for those already treated.